# how to incorporate jquery in user control in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net user control which has 3 textboxes and a dropdown. I want to validate the user control input using jquery but I could not find an event where to write the jquery? The submit button is in the main .aspx pages where this user control is used. I cannot use "form" tag in the user control. Please help.
Following is my jquery code:

```
$("[id*=RequesterDetailform]").validate({
            rules:
            {
                $("[id*=Req_FirstName]"):
                {
                    required: true
                },
                $("[id*=Req_LastName]"):
                {
                    required: true
                },
                $("[id*=Phone]"):
                {
                    required: true                    
                },
                $("[id*=TextFAFM]"):
                {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        },
        messages:
            {
                $("[id*=Req_FirstName]"):
                {
                    required: "Please enter your first name"
                },
                $("[id*=Req_LastName]"):
                {
                    required: "Please enter your last name"
                },
                 $("[id*=Phone]"):
                {
                    required: "Please enter your Phone number"
                },               
                $("[id*=TextFAFM]"):
                {
                    required: "Please enter FA/FM's name"
                }

            }
    });//Ending validate function
```

Following is my code in the main page:

```
       <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMasterData.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PCParentAdd.aspx.cs" Inherits="MasterDataForms.PCParentAdd" EnableViewState="true"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MDM" TagName="RequesterDetailControl" Src="~/RequesterDetailControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CC" TagName="CommentsControl" Src="~/CommentsControl.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Profit Center Parent Addition Request
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="dbe7ef">
<MDM:RequesterDetailControl runat="server" ID="RequesterDetailControlPCParentAdd" bgcolor="dbe7ef"/>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="dbe7ef">                        
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitPCParentAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit Request" 
                                onclick="btnSubmitPCParentAdd_Click"/>  
                            <input type="reset" name="btnReset" value="Reset Form"/></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post your aspx code?

Comment: If your using webforms when the controls are being rendered they get a unique id. In the newer webforms versions you can explicitly set the id by using the property clientId = "myId" and your JQuery will pick this up. To prove this you can view source of the page after it has been rendered and you will see that your button has a different id than you expect.

Comment: I dont have a problem with the Id yet, I am not sure where to place the code so that it gets executed successfully and i dont have to write the code again and again in each and every aspx page using the user control.